# How to save a dying dusty miller?

Tags: plant-health, container-gardening, urban-gardening

[image]
This is my plant and is dying. Although I tried a lot to make it survive its health status depleted with time. Now some of its leaves are still active while rest died (approx 20 percent alive).

This plant is really new to me and I need guiding to care for it. I have googled a lot but found nothing useful. What should I do now?

Comment: Where are you in the world, is it indoors or out,  and how long have you had this plant

Comment: You haven't overwatered it, have you?

Comment: well I really don't mean what overwatering mean here??But yes I took care about that...I watered once every two day...kept in shade with good light(indore)I avoided direct sunlight..because I saw it wasn't comfortable at all..

Comment: @Bamboo I am in INDIA

Comment: Is there a drainage hole in the bottom of the pot? How long have you had the plant? What soil have you used in the pot?

Comment: yes there is single drainage hole at bottom:my plant is..i think 2~3 weeks..)old,Soil type :unidentified...

Comment: I can't see the soil in the pot clearly to judge whether its wet or dry, but it sounds like you're not watering properly - it should be allowed to dry a bit between waterings, so the top of the soil feels just about dry to the touch, and then you water copiously (say half to a litre of water) and allow the excess to drain out the bottom. Are you growing this indoors - it usually grows outdoors in full sun during the summer months in the UK? If it is indoors, don't move it straight into full sun immediately if you decide to put it outside, it will need to acclimatize slowly

Comment: But as i said.its state is still critical. ..what should. I do right now...your suggestion are right but it will work for healthier one.

Comment: When did you water last?  Pop that plant out of its pot by cupping your hand over the top of the plant and holding onto the rim of your pot turn the pot upside down.  Your plant should easily slide out if not just hit the pot or bounce it with your hand inbetween the surface and the pot enough to get the plant released from your pot.  Is there moisture in that soil where the roots are able to reach?  If this is overwatering you probably won't get your plant back.  If this is underwatering most of your plant should come back after watering thoroughly.  Otherwise, root rot from too much H2O.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've used garden soil in this little pot.  Also looks like you've underwatered.  Simply water again (if I am seeing this correctly), allow to drain, dump the water out of saucer, keep as close to a south facing window or on the patio UNDER a roof, no direct sun.

If you have overwatered this plant (kind of looks the same) it is because of the high clay content of your garden soil.  Potting soil is sterilized.  The garden soil will have a few fungal spores, bad bacteria and/or eggs of some insect that normally is kept in check by beneficials in the body of the garden soil.

Potting soil actually has very little soil soil mixed into the medium.  Hard and fast rule in the garden world, anything planted in a pot or a pot like container has to be planted in a sterilized medium, such as bagged potting soil.  It is very much a hassle and stinky to try to make your own potting soil.

Make sure there is no fertilizer added or water holding gimmicks such as sponges or gels.  Just soil in that pot over the drainage hole.  No rocks or gravel below the soil and above the drain hole...will ruin the drainage.

I would transplant this plant into the same pot but dump out the garden soil without bothering to clean the roots.  Plant in fresh potting soil. Careful about the roots as this plant is just beginning to become established.  Don't worry about leaving the garden soil the roots have claimed.  Eventually, there will be mostly potting soil in your pot.

You will need to add fertilizer, I suggest good old Osmocote 14-14-14 all purpose extended release...use half the recommended amounts and number of applications. Just sprinkle on top of your potting soil.  After transplanting and after finding out what this plant was used to in its previous life.  If your new plant has already been fertilized you need to know when and how much and what was used before starting your own fertilizer program.  This plant is normally used as an annual, meant to be replaced each season.  India means this guy will be a perennial that you need to chop back to keep young looking and not scraggly.

From what I've learned trying to help others in India is that it is tough to find potting soil.  Is that correct?

[Dusty Miller care](http://www.thegardenhelper.com/dusty_miller.html)

Comment: I think my soil is more clayey. ...it become hard when dry...i must add some sand to it

Comment: @stormy_ correct. It's tough to find potting soil here in india and pakistsn and even if you do, it's way too expensive which is a bummer for folks like me here who dont own land and have to settle with growing plants in containers. You mentioned trying to make your own potting soil. I'll look that up and hopefully find something that i can work with.

Answer (score 0):

- First you just cut all the dead leaves off
- then make sure your plant gets 4 to 5 hour of sunlight. (If you are just putting in a indoor  plz put your plant in outdoor but not sudden just give it some more light then it get today. And increase it's sunlight hour. Otherwise your plant will go to in shock.
- Just make sure when you give water. You need to give water when a soil is dry. And at that time you give a full water. Water will come out in drainage bowl. Just try this. I make sure your plant can survive....

You also best think if you can do it properly. You just cut your damage leaf and then propagate your plant in a perfect soil mixture. And take care of sunlight and water properly.